# Dijkstra algorith with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, dijkstra

I have the dijkstra algorith in php, and in order to add the edges I have to write:

```
$g= new Graph();
$g->addedge("b", "c", 8);
$g->addedge("b", "e", 2);
```

I want to add all the edges from my database. I have writen:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT Start,End,Distance FROM test_stations");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $g->addedge($row['Start'],$row['End'],$row['Distance']);
    $g->addedge($row['End'],$row['Start'],$row['Distance']);
}
```

But it seems that it does not add the edges. When i try to run it
it prints out: Undefined variable: nodes .
If I run the program by adding manually the edges it works perfectly.
Can somebody help me?

I have this function for the nodes and for the edges.

```
public $nodes = array();

public function addedge($start, $end, $weight = 0) {
  if (!isset($this->nodes[$start])) {
    $this->nodes[$start] = array();
  }
   array_push($this->nodes[$start], new Edge($start, $end, $weight));
}
```

Comment: How do you load your Nodes into the graph before you load your edges?

Comment: it is your own class? you don't have a line number in your error? Without knowing the class `Graph` it's hard to tell..

Comment: You can make it work with RECURSIVE CTE's. Unfortunately, mysql does not have them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess you have not initialised your nodes before you initialised your edges.

Do you load your nodes from the database first, or do you dynamically create them with each edge that refers to an unknown node?